# Return Statement in JavaScript Programming Language

Tags: javascript

Does return mean output? I have checked online the definition of return in programming but there was not any answer that I understood well. I think return a value means output a value but I am not sure.

Comment: How about [learning about it?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Comment: It is a `return` from a function and can be used to return a value.

Comment: Think of the word return to mean result. Which is to say it is the result that is sent back to the caller of the function.

Comment: Returning a value from a function means that value is the value of the function (for the given inputs). Say you have a function `foo` which takes one argument `bar`. If you simply `return bar;` as the body of `foo`, then that means for any value input into the function, it will evaluate to that same value.

Answer (score 1):

Browse the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return):

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.

Answer (score 1):

A function can return a value by using the `return` keyword. When you use this keyword you are exiting the current function and returning the value from where you have called the function. When you are not returning anything `undefined` will be returned.

Example:

```js
function foo() {
  return 10;
}

function bar(){
  let test = foo();
  return test;
}

let result = bar();
console.log(result);
```

1. function bar gets called.
2. This call foo and stores the result of foo in test. foo returns 10.
3. Then bar returns this and stores it in the variable result.